# Inline tool for Linux process time series for CPU and memory

Tags: linux, process, monitoring, ps

I have a Ubuntu server. There are some jobs running. I have to monitor their CPU, memory usage over complete time of their execution (time series). I know there are a lot of CLI tools like top, htop etc. But what I want, is some tool that captures the data (CPU, memory usage) from the system and shows its time series automatically.

Or what is the best approach for this ?

Comment: Will be interested to find out. Maybe `perf` can help?

Answer (score 1):

Is `sysstat` something that could help you? If you enable it, `sar` allows you to print nice reports of usage of cpu & mem (and some other stats). There are some tools that allow you to convert that into graphs then (ksar for instance).

Comment: Instead this across system? Not isolated to process?